# System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ERROR: portal "C_6031" does not exist

Tags: apex, soql, unexpectedexception

Since the Summer 22' release these uncatchable UnexpectedException errors have been popping up sporadically on code that hasn't changed in multiple orgs we manage.
The stacktraces always originate from SOQL statements with `FOR UPDATE`

```
System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ERROR: portal "C_6031" does not exist

SQLState: 34000
File: postgres.c, Routine: exec_execute_message, Line: 2357
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I rather expected some ORA (Oracle error) in the wake of "SfdcSqlException". Are you telling me Salesforce is throwing Postgres errors now? You might look for `ECPG_WARNING_UNKNOWN_PORTAL` [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-errors.html). Not that I believe you can do anything about it.

Comment: I think they switched over to Postgres internally, these errors only happen on Hyperforce org instances.